# Django 2 - Add User Error - group with this name already exists

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

When I try to add a User with a list of groups I get an error stating that "A group with this name already exists". Here are my params:

```
{
 'email': 'test@test.com',
 'first_name': 'Bob',
 'last_name': 'Jones',
 'groups': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8000/api/groups/1/', 'name': 'Admin'}]
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to interact with the Groups model.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'id')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to interact with the Users model.
    """
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='users-detail')
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'username', 'email',
              'groups', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 3):

remove nicely the validator for group name:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'validators': []},
        }
```